# Laravel 5.7 にて connection を指定したクエリビルダのやり方

Tags: php, laravel

## やりたいこと

Laravelにてconnectionを指定したクエリビルダを使いたい

### 例

この方法ではクエリビルダが生成されますが、
connectionは初期状態になります。

```
$builder = \DB::table('table'); // Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
$builder->distinct();
```

以下のように、postgresのコネクションを作成した場合、
クエリビルダではなくコネクションとして生成されます。

```
$builder = \DB::connection('postgresql'); // Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection
$builder->table('table');
$builder->distinct(); // Error
```

もちろんクエリビルダではないので、
`->distinct()` するとエラーになります。

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection::distinct()
```

クエリビルダを生成して、あとからコネクションを設定するか、
コネクションを指定したクエリビルダを生成する方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これでどうですか

```
\DB::connection('postgresql')->select('select * from table');
```

Comment: SQLの実行は可能なのですが、やはりクエリビルダとしては使えないのでしょうか。

Comment: これだとどうでしょう
builder = \DB::connection('postgresql');
$res = $builder->table('table')->select('*')->distinct()->get();

Comment: もしくは、Eloquentを使うのはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます。Eloquentで解決できそうです。